# classify data with unknown labels and validate the result in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, k-means

I have 8 text files, each consists of some data that 300 players used in a game over 8 different fields (in particular, the coordinates of their random walk). I would like to develop and implement a computer algorithm to determine different strategies used by different players.

I started using k-means, I used 6 of those text files as training, and the rest for testing. However, I do not know how I can validate my results. In other words, I would like to know first the number of different classes I should have to minimize the error but I do not know how to define error here. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

#### I. k-Means on trajectories

*k*-Means is an undoubtedly popular and simple algorithm, but it is also a fairly weak one. In particular, it tends to be good at classifying clusters of behaviors within space. The player trajectories ("random walks") you have are possibly a bad fit for *k*-means since you expect the players previous position to have influence on their next position. In essence, the structure of your data involves not simply space, but also time, and this can be difficult for *k*-means. Consider either extracting some features from your trajectories (how erratic, how fast, etc) and clustering atop those dimensions or using an algorithm aimed at temporal correlation like the Hidden Markov Model.

#### II. Validation

In Machine Learning the most common kind of validation is hold-out validation. This is when you have some set of properly classified data and you use part of it for training and part of it as a "target" that the trained model must strive to achieve.

This method doesn't apply in your case, but it's important to examine it. The reason you try to get your model to match a hold-out set is because if you only seek to minimize the error in a model over data it's seen then most ML algorithms will *overfit*. This means that they will become unboundedly better at guessing the data they've seen while becoming increasingly *bad* at predicting new data. Such a model seems great, but is essentially valueless.

Similar things can occur in your situation even though it's an "unsupervised" setting and thus we don't have a labeled training set. If you decided to minimize the error of your *k*-means model and you have *N* training points, then the best chose for *k* is *k = N*. Of course, such a model will simply be identical to your training data and thus useless for any future classification.

Usually the way to handle this situation is via normalization. Instead of minimizing the error, minimize the error *plus* a penalty term for using more clusters (even something like `error + k^2` would be a normalization term of a certain kind). This means that your algorithm will be constrained against picking too high of a *k* since the penalty term will eventually wipe out the winnings.

Under a normalized optimization scheme, you may find yourself in the fortuitous situation where there exists a meaningful optimal value. Is this now the *right* answer?

Sadly, there's no way of knowing. Unsupervised ML simply doesn't, by itself, have an objective. A critic might say that you chose your normalization incorrectly, for instance. However, is it likely to be useful? Well, assuming that there are genuinely some number *l* of different player behaviors that your features could discern then if *k* is close to *l* then your model is doing alright—but all those assumptions are just ghosts in the machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer. Do you think this problem can be solved using expectation maximization algorithm? To me the most difficult task is how to extract some trajectories in order to cluster them accordingly? I really would appreciate your help!

Comment: EM is like a hammer, but your problems are more around choosing whether to build a house or a swimming pool. In either case, EM may or may not be necessary. I would really look into HMM if I were you—it's a natural model for pulling features from trajectories and you can then try to classify the HMM parameters.